# Transparent Oval Border in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, border, transparency

Is it possible to make a transparent and oval border in windows forms? Inner part of the form should not be transparent.

We have a image with a transparent and oval border, we set it as the BackgroundImage of the form. If we use TransparencyKey, borders getting oval but the Form can't clear the TranparencyKey color from the background of the border which causes to lose trancparency. You see the BackColor of the Form on borders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) property to make your form any shape you need.

In addition, WPF allows to do it even simpler. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfpopup.aspx). WPF also provides very simple and useful gradients speicifying way. Here few good links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754083.aspx

http://community.visual-basic.it/alessandroenglish/archive/2009/04/14/25316.aspx

You also can use background image with TransparentKey setting as shown in this example (and looks like you currently have [this solution](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2008/05/19/beauty-is-only-skin-deep-part-deux-if-it-looks-like-a-duck-it-might-be-a-winform.aspx))